# What is the difference between start debugging and Run without debugging

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm building a flutter app in VsCode

When am ready to lunch my app
I use Run -> start debugging in vsCose

But alternatively I can use Run -> Run without debugging

So what the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Debug mode, you can pause your application at so called break points. This can help you to find bugs in your code. You can also figure out, which values your variables consist at a speficic part in your application.

You can set a break point by double clicking on the left of a line number where you want to pause your code from running (see here: [debug break point example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wregd.png))

Answer (score 2):

Debug mode is for development. As such, the binaries are larger and slower, because they have e.g. the names of all your functions stored alongside line number information for debug tracing to work. Hot reloading is also an important feature of development or **debug mode**.

When you run in production mode, all the debug information is stripped away, the app loads much faster, and all debug information is elided from the binary that is produced. It is for end-use.

Answer (score 0):

start debugging mean's in debug mode, it is best when you want to debug your app. you can set multiple break points and check what is value of that variable at particular point of time.

Run without debugging mean simple run where your break points doesn’t matter.

Moreinfo: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is the process of finding and fixing errors or bugs in the source code of any software. When software does not work as expected, computer programmers study the code to determine why any errors occurred. They use debugging tools to run the software in a controlled environment, check the code step by step, and analyze and fix the issue.
Here in flutter debug mode is for development . In this you can give break to the production of your code and start finding the error. Its helps in hot reloading.

In most simple word we can say that :
When you select this option (press F5 ) to run the application, Visual Studio loads all required symbols, “attaches the debugger” and then launches the application.  You should be able to see the assembly loading from the “Debug –> Windows –> Output”’ window.
[8:43 PM]
With this option selected…

You can pause the execution of application by breakpoints
step through the code
Inspect elements
take advantages of all available debugging tools such as Watch Window, Data Tips and Diagnostic Tools etc.
[8:43 PM]
Start without Debugging :

When you select this option (press Ctrl  + F5 ) to run the application, Visual Studio will launch your application without loading the symbols and attaching the Debugger.

In this case

if you have any breakpoint within the code, application won’t pause
you can’t step through the code.
So, this is just run your application in Debug mode with out having debugger attached with it.